# Does queryPurchaseHistoryAsync return purchases from another package?

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

The documentation for [queryPurchaseHistoryAsync](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.html#querypurchasehistoryasync) describes:

> queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(String skuType, PurchaseHistoryResponseListener listener)
>   Returns the most recent purchase made by the user for each SKU, even if that purchase is expired, canceled, or consumed.

My assumption was that this will only return purchases for this SKU belonging to the specific package belonging to the app making the request. Some of my testing results show something else though. Could it be all purchases matching the SKU provided are returned, regardless of the package they belong to?

Answer (score 0):

It will only return SKUs that are related to the calling app.

Comment: Do you have any documentation to back this up? My assumption is the same, but my experience is showing something different.